# Find $a$, $b$ and $c$ that satisfies the given equation.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Recently I have this obsession on palindromic numbers and curious on the difficult (for me) problem.

Is there a pairwise relatively prime integers $a$, $b$ and $c$ satisfying:

$3a=p1$

$4b=p2$

$5c=p3$

Where $p1,p2,p3$ are palindromes?

I'll be waiting for your answers and thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, $a=1,b=1,c=1$.

Comment: Also, $a=11,b=2,c=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a = 101$

$b = 1001 = 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13$

$c = 10001 = 73 \cdot 137$

$3a = 303, 4b = 4004$ and $5c = 50005$ are all palindromes.

Comment: Thanks the problem seems easy with your help, @barak manos thank you also.